# How to find number of cell from numbers of rows and columns of a table?

Tags: algorithm

This may look like a really bad homework but it isn't. I don't know how to call this correctly. It is going to use in tic-tac-toe

I have a table with 3 rows and 3 columns. The structure look like this

```
    1 2 3
    - - -
1 | 1 2 3  <---- Cell number
2 | 4 5 6
3 | 7 8 9
```

I am going to use nested for loop to create a table for tic-tac-toe. For example,When a user click on cell number 1 it will look like this.

```
    1 2 3
    - - -
1 | O 2 3  <---- Cell number 1 is toggled
2 | 4 5 6
3 | 7 8 9
```

I have a problem that I don't know how to assign cell with correct number in for loop. I don't use nested array because it will make code too long.

Comment: "I don't use nested array because it will make code too long": what ???

Comment: Your example seems pretty irrelevant. When a user clicks on a cell, he precisely provides row and column indexes, and there is no loop !!

Comment: Post at least code of your data-structure you intend to use.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's tic-tac-toe win condition will be really long. Single array would suit this game better since it's not so complex.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's about generating table that must have a loop.

Comment: Either you don't explain what the real problem is or this single loop/double loop discussion seems surrealistic. There are just 9 elements, completely unrolled loops could be used.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that you don't want to use a 2D array. Instead, you wish to use a single array and access it as it would be a 2D array. Is this correct?

This means that you have to apply some simple math to your problem.

Based on your description, your 2D table has the same height and width, so height = width.

If you wish to obtain the index of an

```
index = column + width * row
```

If you wish to obtain x and y based on the index:

```
column = index % width;
row = index / width;
```

Comment: I got it. It's `index = column + width * (row-1) `